# Web Speech API: Dom Exception 11

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use the web speech API in Chrome 27 with the following code -

```
$(function(){
    initRecognition();
});

function initRecognition(){
    if(window.recognition !== undefined){
        window.recognition.stop();
        window.recognition.start();
        // ^--- Exception is being thrown at this line
    }else{
        window.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        window.recognition.onresult = function(event) {
          if (event.results.length > 0) {
            command.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            return execute();
          }else{
            command.value = "*&#^$&@^#?";
            return execute();
          }
        };
        window.recognition.continuous = true;
        window.recognition.start();
    }
}

function execute(){
    // some code
    initRecognition();
    return false;
}
```

When the page loads, it asks for permission to start recognition. It recognizes one word or phrase and then stops with the following error -

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
initRecognition
execute
window.recognition.onresult
```

There seem to be lack of resources for this. So having some trouble in troubleshooting. Any idea?

Comment: Most likely the stop method is asynchronous (see https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechreco-methods).  In particular, refer to the documentation regarding the InvalidStateError exception if calling start on an already started object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if I set `continuous` to `true`, I don't have to `stop()` and `start()` every time. And calling `stop()` is what was causing the problem I think. So I removed those statements and it's working fine. :)

```
$(function(){
    initRecognition();
});

function initRecognition(){
    window.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    window.recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        console.log(event.results);
        console.log(event.results.length);
      if (event.results.length > 0) {
        command.value = event.results[event.results.length-1][0].transcript;
        return execute();
      }else{
        command.value = "*&#^$&@^#?";
        return execute();
      }
    };
    window.recognition.continuous = true;
    window.recognition.start();
}

function execute(){
    // some code
    return false;
}
```

Although, for some reason, `event.results` is acting like a stack if `continuous = true` . So I'm fetching the last result of the stack. But I'm sure there are other bugs waiting for me with this.